# Replace filename with file contents within a file in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, text-files

I have a textfile, within which I have a reference to other files.  What I want to do is run a script which will substitute filenames at runtime with the contents of the file, and then curl this to a server.

Can anyone recommend a quick way to do this using powershell or something similar on the windows command line?

e.g.

```
  "responses": [
    {
      "is": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Location": "http://localhost:4545/myresponse",
          "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
        "body": "@file:myresponse.xml"
      }
    }]
```

would become:

```
  "responses": [
    {
      "is": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Location": "http://localhost:4545/myresponse",
          "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
        "body": "<xml> contents of myresponse.xml within same directory.. </xml>"
      }
    }]
```

Comment: are you aware that PoSh has nothing to do with the "windows command line"? -- powershell.exe aint PoSh ;)

Comment: Yes.. I'm not an experienced windows scripter, however I assumed this would be quite difficult to do using regular command line scripting compared to powershell, but wanted to keep my options open :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in PowerShell with something like:

```
$template = Get-Content template.txt -Raw
$template = [regex]::Replace($template, '(@file:.*?)(?=")', {param($f) Get-Content ($f -replace '@file:') -Raw }))
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://example.org/' -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Body $template
```

.... depending on all the specifics of your setup.

Regex replace picks out the bit `@file:` to the following `"` and removes the leading bit. The matches get fed into the scriptblock, which acts to load the file content and that gets replaced back in place of the filename.

If you want to *actually* `curl` it, you'll need a Windows built of `curl.exe`. The PowerShell alias of the same name makes no attempt to behave in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! :)